# Failed to build Retrainer by Bazel

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

When installing  the retrainer in the TensorFlow following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) on OSX(10.9.5) , Bazel:0.2.2-b, CUDA:7.5, cuDNN:v5  python:2.7

```
$bazel build tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain
```

I encountered the following error. Any ideas?

> ERROR: /Users/hoshinotoshihiko/tensorflow/google/protobuf/BUILD:272:1:
>   C++ compilation of rule '//google/protobuf:protoc' failed:
>   osx_cc_wrapper.sh failed:
>
> error executing command 
>   (cd/private/var/tmp/_bazel_hoshinotoshihiko/ff5db7423b3afa0d045a736d77207f89/tensorflow
>   && \exec env - 
>   \PATH='/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/Users/hoshinotoshihiko/exec -l
>   /bin/bash/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/hoshinotoshihiko/bin'TMPDIR=/var/folders/y6/78v3zz4j1bj6nq7bl82c3cj80000gn/T/
>   \external/local_config_cc/osx_cc_wrapper.sh -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE
>   '-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1' -fstack-protector -Wall -Wthread-safety
>   -Wself-assign -Wunused-but-set-parameter -Wno-free-nonheap-object -fcolor-diagnostics -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g0 -O2 -DNDEBUG -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -g0 '-std=c++0x' -iquote . -iquote bazel-out/host/genfiles -iquote external/bazel_tools -iquote
>   bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/bazel_tools -isystem
>   google/protobuf/src -isystem
>   bazel-out/host/genfiles/google/protobuf/src -isystem
>   external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 -no-canonical-prefixes
>   -fno-canonical-system-headers -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined '-D__DATE__="redacted"' '-D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted"'
>   '-D__TIME__="redacted"'
>   '-frandom-seed=bazel-out/host/bin/google/protobuf/_objs/protoc/google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.o'
>   -MD -MF bazel-out/host/bin/google/protobuf/_objs/protoc/google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.d
>   -c google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc -o bazel-out/host/bin/google/protobuf/_objs/protoc/google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.o):
>
> com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process
>   exited with status 126.
>
> external/local_config_cc/osx_cc_wrapper.sh: line 56:
>   /usr/local/lib/gcc: is a directory
>
> Target //tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain failed to build
>
> INFO: Elapsed time: 20.672s, Critical Path: 20.22s

Comment: What does `which gcc` returns? and `echo "x$CCx"`?

Comment: `which gcc` returns /usr/bin/gcc, `echo "x$CCx"` returns x .

Comment: It was because of the performance of the machine.
Thank you for your replay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of the performance of the machine.
By changing the machine(MacBook Air(Mid2012)(4GB memory)→MacBook Pro(Mid2014)(16GB memory), I was able to build.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with google's dockerfile for tensor flow:

https://tensorflow.googlesource.com/tensorflow/+/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel

If you have trouble in that environment, re-post.

Comment: I did not know how to do this, but I will try later by referring to [this](https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/)
Thank you for your reply!